# Taylor series vs numeric solution of nonlinear DE in maple

Tags: maple

I want to plot two graphs: numeric solution of DE and Taylor series approximation for DE given. I have

```
de := diff(y(x), x$2) = x+y(x)-y(x)^2;
cond := y(0) = -1, (D(y))(0) = 1;
stp := 0.1e-1;
a, b := -5, 30;
numpts := floor((b-a)/stp+1);
p := dsolve({cond, de}, y(x), numeric, stepsize = stp, output = listprocedure);
```

Plotting `eval` gives weird vertical line, while I expect to obtain plot that seems to oscillate as `x -> ∞`. For Taylor series, I've tried `f:=[seq(taylor(y(x),x=i,n),i=-5..30 by stp)];` but seems like it won't work in such a way. What can I do with it? Why does my plot differ from expected?

Comment: Recently, another question of yours seems to have  disappeared. Is that right? Was it deleted?

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, plot looks right. 
My last question was useless because it arose from my wrong ideas about result. In fact, Maple automatically does what was needed if it can be done in such a way, so question was unnecessary. Simple check (using another similar DE) shown me that my "problem" is problem of my math skills rather than my Maple skills :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
restart;
kernelopts(version);

    Maple 2018.0, X86 64 LINUX, Mar 9 2018, Build ID 1298750

de := diff(y(x), x$2) = x+y(x)-y(x)^2:
cond := y(0) = -1, (D(y))(0) = 1:
stp := 0.1e-1:
a, b := -5, 30:
numpts := floor((b-a)/stp+1):

p := dsolve({cond, de}, y(x), numeric, stepsize = stp,
            output = listprocedure):

Y:=eval(y(x),p);

                Y := proc(x)  ...  end;

plot(Y, 0..20);
```

[image]

```
Order:=10:
S := convert(rhs(dsolve({cond, de}, {y(x)}, series)),polynom);

plot([S, Y(x)], x=0..1.5);
```

[image]

```
Order:=40:
S := convert(rhs(dsolve({cond, de}, {y(x)}, series)),polynom):

plot([S, Y(x)], x=0..2.0);
```

[image]